How can I use DXVK with Wine to run World of Warcraft 3.3.5a?
I am on Linux Mint 21.3 and I have installed Wine 6.0.3 and got it to run the 3.3.5a World of Warcraft client out of the box. However, sometimes I experience noticeable stuttering while playing the game, and I read that DXVK could be used to improve the performance of older DirectX applications, so I tried this:

I downloaded the latest release version of DXVK (currently version 2.3.1)

I ran the commands described on the DXVK GitHub page
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine
cp x64/*.dll $WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/system32
cp x32/*.dll $WINEPREFIX/drive_c/windows/syswow64

I configured Wine to override the DirectX 9 library by changing the load order of d3d9 to native, builtin


When I launch the game client with wine Wow.exe, I see this error:
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x00000000).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:006b GS:0063
 EIP:00000000 ESP:02b5eeec EBP:02b5ef78 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:0016e808 EBX:01c7acd8 ECX:00000000 EDX:02b5ef18
 ESI:00000000 EDI:01c79e30
Stack dump:
0x02b5eeec:  6254d7de 0016e808 02b5ef18 02b5ef38
0x02b5eefc:  6a2a6ae6 626d7280 00000000 01c8be08
0x02b5ef0c:  01c79e30 02b5f00c 02b5ef90 3b9f9493
0x02b5ef1c:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x02b5ef2c:  00000000 00000000 00000003 01c8e010
0x02b5ef3c:  6269690c 01c79e20 01c762c0 02b5ef98
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00000000 (0x02b5ef78)
  1 0x624d4ced in d3d9 (+0x94cec) (0x02b5efd8)
  2 0x624744dd in d3d9 (+0x344dc) (0x02b5f078)
  3 0x62476580 in d3d9 (+0x3657f) (0x02b5f0e8)
  4 0x6246e586 in d3d9 (+0x2e585) (0x02b5f248)
  5 0x6246ec58 in d3d9 (+0x2ec57) (0x02b5faac)
  6 0x62442507 in d3d9 (+0x2506) (0x02b5fb88)
  7 0x0069055d EntryPoint+0x28f55c() in wow (0x02b5fc04)
  8 0x00682cc7 EntryPoint+0x281cc6() in wow (0x02b5fc10)
  9 0x006907fb EntryPoint+0x28f7fa() in wow (0x02b5fc30)
  10 0x006812df EntryPoint+0x2802de() in wow (0x02b5fc40)
  11 0x0076af05 EntryPoint+0x369f04() in wow (0x02b5fcf0)
  12 0x00406b2d EntryPoint+0x5b2c() in wow (0x02b5ff40)
  13 0x00406d19 EntryPoint+0x5d18() in wow (0x02b5ff50)
  14 0x0040b7d8 EntryPoint+0xa7d7() in wow (0x02b5ff58)
  15 0x7b072b57 AccessCheckByType+0xb816() in kernelbase (0x02b5ffe8)
0x00000000: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (36 modules)
PE    390000-  3ba000   Deferred        zlib1
PE    400000-  dfd000   Export          wow
PE    e00000- 1266000   Deferred        ole32
PE   1270000- 1715000   Deferred        comctl32
PE   1720000- 1886000   Deferred        winmm
PE  10000000-10069000   Deferred        divxdecoder
PE  61740000-61832000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  61940000-61b21000   Deferred        wininet
PE  62440000-6281e000   Export          d3d9
PE  62fc0000-631d3000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  63480000-6349b000   Deferred        version
PE  63bc0000-63c04000   Deferred        shcore
PE  64a40000-64b29000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  666c0000-666e8000   Deferred        hid
PE  68500000-68640000   Deferred        combase
PE  68700000-68788000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  69ac0000-69ada000   Deferred        vulkan-1
PE  6a040000-6a0a2000   Deferred        msacm32
PE  6a280000-6a4cd000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  6bc00000-6bc99000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6bcc0000-6be60000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6c9c0000-6cf59000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  6ed00000-6f389000   Deferred        user32
PE  6fa80000-6fb95000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE  70940000-70994000   Deferred        mpr
PE  70b40000-70df9000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  71200000-71251000   Deferred        imm32
PE  7a820000-7a824000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b000000-7b348000   Dwarf           kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b929000   Deferred        kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bea9000   Deferred        ntdll
PE  7e940000-7e944000   Deferred        winex11
PE  7ea10000-7f2e2000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7f8e0000-7f8eb000   Deferred        dinput8
PE  7f940000-7f946000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  f1450000-f1454000   Deferred        winevulkan
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000020 (D) Z:\home\mihkel\Documents\World of Warcraft 3.3.5a\Wow.exe
    00000024    0 <==
    000000f4    0
    000000f8    0
    000000fc    0
    00000100    0
    00000104    0
    00000110    0
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0
    00000040    0
    0000004c    0
    00000050    0
    00000070    0
    00000088    0
    000000b8    0
    000000bc    0
    000000d0    0
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0
    00000054    0
    00000058    0
    0000005c    0
00000060 explorer.exe
    00000064    0
    000000a4    0
    000000a8    0
00000068 plugplay.exe
    0000006c    0
    00000074    0
    00000078    0
    0000007c    0
    00000098    0
    0000009c    0
00000080 winedevice.exe
    00000084    0
    0000008c    0
    00000090    0
    00000094    0
    000000a0    0
000000ac svchost.exe
    000000b0    0
    000000c0    0
    000000c4    0
000000c8 rpcss.exe
    000000cc    0
    000000d4    0
    000000d8    0
    000000dc    0
    000000e0    0
    000000e4    0
    000000e8    0
000000ec conhost.exe
    000000f0    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 6.5.0-41-generic

I can always remove the override from the Wine configuration and the game works just like it did before, but I am interested in trying out DXVK to see if it can improve overall performance.
I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, because I am at a loss as to how I would troubleshoot this issue any further.

So remind those who are unfamiliar running this particular version of the WoW client. Was it 32-bit or 64-bit? There is a good chance the problem is DXVK.

It is a 32-bit client.
